# Загрузка файла для передачи функции в РНР

Tags: php, fileupload

Есть файл index.php, в кейсе

```
case 'importLoading':
 importLoading();
 break;
```

В самой функции `importLoading()`идет вызов `Loading::import()` и указание на шаблон `require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/importLoading.php" );`, после чего импортируется и разбирается файл `$xls = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('./test.xls');`.

Хочу указать файл для обработки через форму. Пробую делать в 
    `importLoading()` 
    `$results = array();
    $results['formAction'] = 'importLoading';
    $loading = Loading::import( (int)$_POST['uploadfile'] )
    $loading->import($uploadfile);`

В функции import: 
`

```
public function import($uploadfile) {
$uploaddir = './uploads/';
$uploads = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
// Копируем файл из каталога для временного хранения файлов:
// Проверяем загружен ли файл
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"]))
{
// Если файл загружен успешно, перемещаем его
// из временной директории в конечную
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploads);
} else {
echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
}
etc...`
```

выдает ошибку, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Открою маленькую тайну. В "ошибке" написано, что именно ты делаешь не так. Надо только прочитать.

Comment: Ошибку я вижу, но немогу понять, где именно загвоздка. Сам файл не загружается или функция его не принимает.

Comment: (int)$_POST['uploadfile'] - это что такое?

Comment: старый код, проверку на инт не ведется

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю $uploadfile это файл, переменная, который как параметр принимает функция. Для указания индексов в ассоциативном массиве с помощью переменных не нужно указывать их вот так $_FILES["uploadfile"], у вас же это переменная, попробуйте вот так вот $_FILES[$uploadfile]. Надеюсь поможет.